# Only return ids for entity relations from doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Doctrine entity:

```
class Thing
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

     /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=45)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project\Bundle\ModelBundle\Entity\ThingGroup", cascade={"persist"})
     * @var type 
     */
    private $thingGroup;
```

Controller :

```
public function getThingsByThingGroupAction($id) {

    $things= $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
                ->getRepository('ProjetModelBundle:Thing')
                ->findBy(array('thingGroup'=>$id));

    return $things;
}
```

This is returning an array of Things with the whole ThingGroup relation entity inside each item. I want to send this result to my client side in json format but I don't want to send the whole ThingGroup for each entity, only the id of the relation would be needed. I can make some DTO operations to handle this, but is there a way directly threw Docrtine to return only ids for relations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use the query builder to build your query according to your needs. But I will recommend a better way: use a serializer. You can use JMSSerializerBundle, as is much greater than the serializer that Symfony comes with. Using JMSSerializer you will easily configure your entity to expose certain parameters, how to expose them and when.

https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle

Comment: OK thanks, JMS is doing the job, espacially with the "Exclude" and "VirtualProperty" annotations combination.